# Generating Unique Random Numbers Efficiently

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

We are using the technique outlined [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3055/generating-random-numbers-in-sql-server-without-collisions/) to generate random record IDs without collisions. In short, we create a randomly-ordered table of every possible ID, and mark each record as 'Taken' as it is used.

I use the following Stored Procedure to obtain an ID:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spc_GetId @retVal BIGINT OUTPUT
AS
  DECLARE @curUpdate TABLE (Id BIGINT);

  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  UPDATE IdMasterList SET Taken=1 
    OUTPUT DELETED.Id INTO @curUpdate
    WHERE ID=(SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM IdMasterList WITH (INDEX(IX_Taken)) WHERE Taken IS NULL ORDER BY SeqNo);

  SELECT TOP 1 @retVal=Id FROM @curUpdate;
  RETURN;
```

The retrieval of the ID must be an atomic operation, as simultaneous inserts are possible.

For large inserts (10+ million), the process is quite slow, as I must pass through the table to be inserted via a cursor.

The IdMasterList has a schema:

```
SeqNo (BIGINT, NOT NULL) (PK) -- sequence of ordered numbers
Id (BIGINT)                   -- sequence of random numbers
Taken (BIT, NULL)             -- 1 if taken, NULL if not
```

The IX_Taken index is:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX (IX_Taken) ON IdMasterList (Taken ASC)
```

I generally populate a table with Ids in this manner:

```
DECLARE @recNo BIGINT;
DECLARE @newId BIGINT;
DECLARE newAdds CURSOR FOR SELECT recNo FROM Adds
OPEN newAdds;

FETCH NEXT FROM newAdds INTO @recNo;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 BEGIN
  EXEC spc_GetId @newId OUTPUT;
  UPDATE Adds SET id=@newId WHERE recNo=@recNo;
  FETCH NEXT FROM newAdds INTO @id;
END;

CLOSE newAdds;
DEALLOCATE newAdds;
```

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way I can improve the SP to extract Ids faster?
2. Would a conditional index improve peformance (I've yet to test, as
   IdMasterList is *very* big)?
3. Is there a better way to populate a table with these Ids?

Comment: What's the purpose of random IDs? Why not rowversion/guid/auto-increment?

Comment: Why not pass a parameter to the SP to specify the number of values you need and have it return a rowset with the specified number of values? `TOP` can deal with a number larger than `1`. (Tip: It would help if you would tag your question with the _version_ of SQL Server that you're using.)

Comment: So that person with a particular ID cannot guess who the person is with the previous or next ID. Auto-increment would not be good for this reason. Requirement was also for a 10 digit number, so GUID was out. Finally, I believe rowversion would sequence similarly to auto-increment, so it was not a good fit.

Comment: @HABO, that's an interesting idea. When I know I have the table all to myself (rare), I will grab them in bulk, and it is a lot faster.

Comment: You're doing inserts with over 10+ million IDs, but you only have a 10 digit number? Those are going to run out quite fast...

Comment: @JameZ, 10 digits give you nearly 10 billion IDs. We're not worried.

Comment: Not quite how but somehow insert them with a null ID and then do a join with output to update.

Comment: @Frisbee, I have done this when I have the table all to myself; I will join via the 'Adds' table's recNo field plus an offset. But it doesn't lend itself well to multi-user inserts.

Comment: Using readpast hint might help, so that other transactions could take numbers from the table, if locking is the problem for getting more than 1 row at the time.

Comment: You have multiple users performing concurrent inserts of 10+ million each?     How does it not lend to multi-user inserts?  It is going to be faster than one at time loop?

Comment: @Frisbee - There is a more or less steady stream of single inserts. The 10+ million jobs are monthly inserts (and hopefully getting less as time goes on).

Comment: Then have two procedures.   The cursor is killing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most things in SQL Server, if you are using cursors, you are doing it wrong.

Since you are using SQL Server 2012, you can use a `SEQUENCE` to keep track of what random value you already used and effectively replace the `Taken` column.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SeqNoSequence
    AS bigint
    START WITH 1    -- Start with the first SeqNo that is not taken yet
    CACHE 1000;     -- Increase the cache size if you regularly need large blocks
```

Usage:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    recNo       bigint,
    SeqNo       bigint
)

INSERT INTO #tmp (recNo, SeqNo)
    SELECT      recNo,
                NEXT VALUE FOR SeqNoSequence
    FROM        Adds

UPDATE Adds
    SET         id = m.id
    FROM        Adds            a
    INNER JOIN  #tmp            tmp     ON a.recNo = tmp.recNo
    INNER JOIN  IdMasterList    m       ON tmp.SeqNo = m.SeqNo
```

`SEQUENCE` is atomic. Subsequent calls to `NEXT VALUE FOR SeqNoSequence` are guaranteed to return unique values, even for parallel processes. Note that there can be gaps in `SeqNo`, but it's a very small trade off for the huge speed increase.

Comment: Did you mean to say there cannot be gaps in SeqNo?

Comment: `NEXT VALUE FOR ....` returns n, n + 1, n + 2, ... most of the time. But there are cases where it skips a few numbers, so some `SeqNo` from your `IdMasterList` table may never be used. See more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Put a PK inden of BigInt on each table

```
insert into user (name)  
values ()..... 

update user set = user.ID = id.ID  
  from id
  left join usr 
    on usr.PK = id.PK 
 where user.ID = null;
```

one

```
insert into user (name) value ("justsaynotocursor");
set @PK = select select SCOPE_IDENTITY();
update user set ID = (select ID from id where PK = @PK);
```

Answer (score 1):

Few ideas that came to my mind:

- Try if removing the top, inner select etc. helps to improve the performance of the ID fetching (look at statistics io & query plan):

  ```
  UPDATE top(1) IdMasterList 
  SET @retVal = Id, Taken=1
  WHERE Taken IS NULL
  ```
- Change the index to be a filtered index, since I assume you don't need to fetch numbers that are taken. If I remember correctly, you can't do this for NULL values, so you would need to change the Taken to be 0/1.
- What actually is your problem? Fetching single IDs or 10+ million IDs? Is the problem CPU / I/O etc. caused by the cursor & ID fetching logic, or are the parallel processes being blocked by other processes?
- Use sequence object to get the SeqNo. and then fetch the Id from idMasterList using the value returned by it. This could work if you don't have gaps in IdMasterList sequences.
- Using READPAST hint could help in blocking, for CPU / I/O issues, you should try to optimize the SQL.
- If the cause is purely the table being a hotspot, and no other easy solutions seem to help, split it into several tables and use some kind of simple logic (even @@spid, rand() or something similar) to decide from which table the ID should be fetched. You would need more checking if all tables have free numbers, but it shouldn't be that bad.
- Create different procedures (or even tables) to handle fetching of single ID, hundreds of IDs and millions of IDs.